# What is the most efficient method to process a String Freemarker syntax in Java

Tags: java, freemarker

Here is our use case. We are loading freemarker syntax from the database and processing it. We are processing close to a million of records. Things are working fine. But when I profile the application, I see that my freemarker processing method is the bottleneck and it is taking most time. Having read the freemarker documentation, I got some pointers on what my issue would be. Everytime I am doing processing, I am creating new freemarker.template.Template object (creation of which seems expensive). I could not find what would be the right/more efficient way of doing this.

```
public FTLTemplateEngine() {
        cfg = new Configuration();      
    }    



public String process(String template, Map<String, Object> input) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        String rc = null;
        final Writer out = new StringWriter();      
        try {           
            final Template temp =new Template("TemporaryTemplate", new StringReader(template), cfg);
            temp.process(input, out);
        }
        catch (InvalidReferenceException e) {
                log.error("Unable to process FTL - " + template);
            throw new InvalidReferenceException("FTL expression has evaluated to null or it refers to something that doesn't exist.  - " + template, Environment.getCurrentEnvironment());
        }
        catch (TemplateException e) {
            log.error("Unable to process FTL - " + template);
            throw new TemplateException("Unable to process FTL - " + template, e, Environment.getCurrentEnvironment());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Unable to process FTL - " + template);
            throw new IOException("Unable to process FTL - " + template);
        }
        rc = out.toString();
        out.close();
        return rc.trim();
    }
```

Have a look the process method which is called every time Freemarker needs to be parsed. In this method we are creating new Template object everytime. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: `Template.process` is what executes the template, `new Template` does the parsing. Or do you mean *your* process method takes the time, which does both? Anyway, you should do some more detailed analysis to tell anything about this.

Comment: @ddekany,  new Template("TemporaryTemplate", new StringReader(template), cfg) takes most of the time. Processing is pretty fast.

Comment: So then, it seems you will have to cache the resulting `Template`-s. If it's indeed too slow for your application, that is.

Comment: @Anil I am also facing the same issue, `new Template()` is taking time. Did you manage to get any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIR you normally don't call the `Template` constructor directly, but use a `Configuration` instance to do that (see [Get the template](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_gettemplate.html) and [Template loading](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html)). The `Configuration` object also employs [caching](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html#pgui_config_templateloading_caching), which could help. You might need to write your own [`TemplateLoader`](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/cache/TemplateLoader.html) in order to load your FreeMarker templates from the database.

Comment: Of course, caching can be done without `Configuration` too, by caching the newly created `Template`-s.

Comment: Yep, caching can be done without `Configuration`, you are right.